# Find all textboxes where id does not contain certain characters

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-filter

I have the following code and I'm trying to retrieve the txtboxes where `id` does not contain the the word `OT`.

```
<input type="text" id="txtMo1">
<input type="text" id="txtOTMo1">
<input type="text" id="txtTu1">
<input type="text" id="txtOTTu1">
...
...
<input type="text" id="txtMo4">
<input type="text" id="txtOTMo4">
<input type="text" id="txtTu4">
<input type="text" id="txtOTTu4">
...
...
```

I tried using `.find` where `id` starts with `txt` but it gives me everything (obviously). How do I retrieve only the textboxes where id starts with `txt` but does not contain `OT`?

```
.find("input[id ^= 'txt']")
```

Comment: If you're the one generating this markup, consider making use of classes: `<input type="text" id="txtOTMo1" class="cal cal-ot cal-mo">`. Then you can simply do `$(".cal").not(".cal-ot")` etc.

Comment: Yes, I'm generating the markup (using jtemplates). Thanks for the excellent idea. I think it will have less overhead as well. Learning new things with jquery everyday!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use a selector: use `filter`:

```
.find('input[id^="txt"]').filter(function() {
    return -1 === this.id.indexOf('OT');
});
```

The callback to `filter` should return `true` if the element should be kept and `false` if it should be removed. In this case, the function will return `true` and the element will be kept if `indexOf` returns `-1`, which means that `OT` is not present.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much! Quick question if you don't mind -- why did you use `===` instead of `==`?

Comment: @enigma Here, there's no particular reason; it doesn't make much difference. Frequently, however, there is a difference in meaning, and I think it's a good habit to always use `===` except where you *mean* `==`.

Comment: regarding "why did you use === instead of ==?" please look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a class instead for those specific textboxes and use a class selector instead?

But still if you need a solution here it is.

```
$('input[id^-"txt"]').filter(function() {
    return this.id.indexOf('OT') == -1;
});
```

You can render your mark something like this and make your code simple.

Mark up

```
<input type="text" id="txtMo1">
<input type="text" class="OT" id="txtOTMo1">
<input type="text" id="txtTu1">
<input type="text" class="OT"id="txtOTTu1">
```

Js

```
$('input.OT').doYourStuff();
```